# Magento error after clicking Place order

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, email-templates, ce-1.9.2.4

I get this error when trying to place an order:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter::getInlineCssFile() in
>   /.../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php
>   on line 313

I updated Magento to the latest version (1.9.2.4) and cleared cache but I still get this error.

The function `getInlineCssFile()` is in `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php` file.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the Magento autoload is not working providing the file is in the correct place and the class name hasn't been changed.

I would do the following:

1. Download the latest version of Magento
2. Replace the app/Mage.php file and lib/Varien/Autoload.php file as they are responsible for autoloading a class

I would then check make a test order and see if fixes it. If it doesn't I would disable all community and local modules and try again and see does it work.

If it does then I would start re-enabling a few modules at a time until I found the module which caused the issue.

Comment: It's still the same.
Even if I delete the Template.php file I still get this error... (I'm 100% that I deleted the right file :))

Comment: After looking at the code its loading the class just before the try/catch on line 304 of  the class Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template. Can you add Mage::log($processor, null, 'email_class.log', true); just before the try and catch and see what class is logged and then remove the Mage::log

Comment: I don't think it even gets to here. No log file is created. And even if I remove the line 313 in Template.php I still get the same error. Even if I remove everything from this file the error is still there. It's like it's using some other file. I did clear cache and it doesn't help. :S

Comment: If you create a test.php file on your local env and add the following gist, do you get a class name when you run test.php ? https://gist.github.com/colinmurphy/2fabf460a1b5a3e5e4bf

Comment: I ended up reinstalling magento. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. So is the issue now resolved :)